# Android layouts for different screen sizes

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I am struggling for layouts for an Android app. I have defined different layouts for different screen sizes and the current layout directory structure is something like this:

- layout
- layout-land
- layout-small
- layout-xlarge
- layout-xlarge-land

**Problem**

The main layout directory files are being displayed for `3.7 to 7.0` which is a very broad range. And text overlap on small screens and if I adjust on small; it becomes very tiny on the large screen.

According to me, the layout small files should be rendered for smaller screens but those files are only rendered for android wear devices.

layout-xlarge seems to work for `Nexus 9 to Nexus 10`

I want to know, how can I define the different layout for `3.7-5.0` and `5.0-7.0` screen sizes.

Comment: You should use [Size Qualifiers](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseSizeQuali) instead of Configuration Qualifiers to have more control

Comment: As pointed out by @maRShmallow, the size qualifiers you've listed have been deprecated since Android API level 13. A more reliable classification system is the `sw<N>dp` configuration qualifiers which define the smallest width (sw) in dp of the screen in use. For example, I have run into size qualifiers classifying a Nexus 6 as a "tablet", but I was able to remedy this knowing that device is under sw600dp, the cutoff for standard 7" tablets. Source: 
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support

Comment: thank you, but same issue with `sw<N>dp` qualifier. The 320dp layout file is displayed for `3.7` to `6.0`. Any solution?

Comment: don't need to make multiple layout just remember don't fix size of layout.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The answer is already given by **user5594218** but looks like you are still unclear. (maybe you are beginner)

So, here is the **step by step guideline**

**Solution 1:** (short and simple)

1. **Navigate** to `app > src > main > res`
2. **Duplicate** layout directory by copying and pasting
3. **Rename** duplicated Directories e.g `layout-sw300dp`

**Solution 2:** (bit lengthy)

1. Create new resource directory: `res > New > Android resource directory`

[image: Create new resource directory]

2. Select `Resource Type` as `layout`
3. Add `sw<N>dp` in Directory name e.g `layout-sw300dp` and Hit **OK**

[image]

4. Navigate to `app > src > main > res`
5. Copy layouts XML file inside new directory

   ```
   //repeat process for other qualifiers
   ```

**List of Qualifiers to support all screens:**

- layout-sw300dp
- layout-sw330dp
- layout-sw480dp
- layout-sw600dp
- layout-sw720dp

**Testing:**

This is how it gonna look like, if you did it right.
[image]

For more detail and examples, check: [Android Application Development All-in-One For Dummies](https://books.google.com.pk/books?id=lwklCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA456&lpg=PA456&dq=how%20to%20create%20sw300dp%20layout%20file)

Comment: You are right and now I completely understand. Thank you so much for your effort :)

Answer (score 4):

Create folders like the following

```
layout-sw300dp
layout-sw330dp
layout-sw480dp 
layout-sw600dp 
layout-sw720dp
```

Create also values-folders like

```
values-sw300dp 
values-sw330dp 
values-sw480dp
values-sw600dp
values-sw720dp
```

Comment: why do I need to create different values directories? And I have created `layout-sw320dp` and problem is same. It renders 320dp file for `3.7` to `6.0`

Comment: Values directories are required to mention all sizes of your views like textview, imageview etc. And you have to create all the layout folders which i have mentioned in above answer.

Comment: check this 320dp: a typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800 hdpi, etc).
480dp: a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi).
600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).
720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).

Comment: thank you so much, now I understand your answer with the help of Atlas_Gondal guideline. :) Can you give me an example or different values folder?

Comment: Just to clarify, I don't need to use `layout-small` etc when I am using `layout-sw300dp` structure. Correct?

Comment: Yes...layout-land
layout-small
layout-xlarge
layout-xlarge-land these are deprecated, instead of those you have to use new qualifiers which i have mentioned in my answer.

Comment: different values folder means for layout-sw300dp you have to create values-sw300dp, in that create dimens.xml, Suppose in your layout-sw300dp folder you have activity_main.xml, in that some user name textview is there for that textview size should mention in dimens.xml Example android:textSize="@dimens/text_size", in your values-sw300dp in dimens folder mention text size like <dimen name="text_size">16sp</dimen> like this mention the sizes for different layouts in different value dimens according to your requirement. Hope you will understand this

Answer (score 1):

**Navigate**  app-> res-> layout and right click then New-> layout resource file write the filename correctly and from available qualifiers choose the size you want.

Answer (score 0):

Dear you don't need to declare layout for various screen. just make single layout for every screen and don't fix the width and height of layout. you have to keep height either match parent and wrap content as well as for width.

Answer (score -1):

you should try dp in your layout-height/layout-width/textsize as it is independent of screen sizes.