# Android supporting different screen size

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-size

I found many solutions, but nothing works for me. I am creating a language learning application. So in that I am using imageviews, buttons, textviews and webviews. There will be more than 15 layout files. And the solutions i have found seem like I have to create layouts like below.

layout-small

layout-normal

layout -land

layout-land-small

So I have to modify those 15 layout files for these 4 folders. It will be difficult to code as my file count is higher. Instead of modifying files is there any other way to do? If so please help me. Or suggest me how I can handle this for a large number of files.

Comment: there is this library which auto adust fixed defined sizes of views as per screen resolution
you can give a try to it. https://github.com/intuit/sdp

Comment: adjust your layout component at run time.

Comment: @Ankit can you please give me an example?

Comment: @Arshad i am using eclipse and the link you have mentioned is of studio. So is that the same i have to do in eclipse?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44962954/4336740

Comment: @Tweety check my ans

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to support different screen size in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255985/how-to-support-different-screen-size-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

> **There is no need to create separate layout directories**

**You can refer to this:**

**For Layouts Consistency refer and use (example is given below):** https://github.com/intuit/sdp

> **Note:** Margin , Padding , Height, Width, etc can be used with `sdp` for best results.

**in your `gradle` :** `implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.5'`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_200sdp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/_4sdp">
      <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_12sdp"          // SDP used
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_12sdp"             // SDP used
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_12sdp"           // SDP used
        android:background="@drawable/shape_button_background"
        android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"                              // SP used
        android:text="@string/str_confirm_place_order"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**For Font Size Consistency :** *I will recommend you to use `sp` instead of others.*

> **Note:** textSize in Button,EditText,TextView etc can be used with `sp` for best results.

```
               <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvFbShare"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:padding="@dimen/_6sdp"             // SDP used
                    android:text="@string/str_share_on_facebook"
                    android:textColor="@color/fb_blue"
                    android:textSize="14sp"                   // SP used />
```

Comment: Even for buttons, images, webview i can use sp and it will be the same for all screen size? I am using eclipse.

Comment: For buttons, images, webview you can go for using "SDP" and where you want to apply textSize go for "SP", try it, you will get results the way you want

Comment: Sure i'll try and let you know. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks again. I will try.

Comment: Sure! Let me know if more inputs required

Answer (score 0):

You can also use values/dimens.xml to define dimensions for different screen sizes. Then you only need to use these dimensions in your layout files. As for landscape/portrait, you will probably have to deal with 2 layout files.

Comment: For landscape/portrait i have to create seperate layouts? Is it what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

no need use 4 folder for each layout best solution use [sdp](https://github.com/intuit/sdp)

Comment: So for arranging buttons or textview or images i am hard coding.

Comment: Okay. Thanks I'll try and let you know :)

Answer (score -1):

First of all Define these two methods in your Utility class

```
// Method is used to get the height of the screen
public static int getScreenHeight(Context context) {

    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    assert wm != null;
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getMetrics(metrics);
    return metrics.heightPixels;
}

// Method is used to get the width of the screen
public static int getScreenWidth(Context context) {

    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    assert wm != null;
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getMetrics(metrics);
    return metrics.widthPixels;
}
```

Use above two methods to get the height and width of the screen in **onCreate()**

```
int height = Utility.getScreenHeight(this);
int width = Utility.getScreenWidth(this);
```

Now you can use these dimensions in **onResume()** method like

```
your_ui_component.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (height * .25);
your_ui_component.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (height * .25);
```

Change .25 with your required dimension

Comment: Thanks. I will try and let you know.