# Is there any way to force Android to choose a particular layout for a particular screen size?

Tags: android, layout, screen

I am a newbie Android developer and having a little problem. I have designed a screen layout for small screens (eg. 2.7" 240 x 320) with screen size qualifier it worked perfectly. Now when I designed layout for normal screens using smallest screen width qualifier. The app is working normal for normal screen phones but for small screen size (say 2.7"inches) the android is skipping the small screen layout and choosing the sw320dp qualifier layout.

So, is there any way so that android must choose small size screen layout (for 2.7"inches) and for normal screen phones it must choose sw320dp qualifier screen layout.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the classification is inclusive, ie it'll include your small display. Use a higher value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android layouts for different screen sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44962692/android-layouts-for-different-screen-sizes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `swXXXdp` resource qualifier is known as the *smallest width* qualifier. Using `sw320dp` tells the system to use those values for any device with a smallest width of **at least** 320dp. Therefore, if you're trying to create one layout for phones with **exactly** 320dp, and another layout for any phone **larger** than 320dp, you'd need to use a different number in your resource qualifier.

In your case, you could probably solve the problem by changing your directory to be `layout-sw321dp`.

In my experience, the common cutoffs I used were:

- `layout` for small phones
- `layout-sw360dp` for modern (larger) phones
- `layout-sw600dp` for seven-inch tablets
- `layout-sw720dp` for ten-inch tablets

Comment: thank you buddy ! tried everything but nothing worked except your answer, you made my day.Solved my problem.