# How to desgin an UI which will work on multiple screens?

Tags: android

So I have two phones Note 3 (5.7in 1080p) here is a screenshot of the app: 
[image]

And I also have A7 2018 (6in 1080x2220 18.5:9) here is a screenshot: 
[image]

After seeing the massive difference how can I make stable UI across multi-screen sizes and resolutions, and what makes the situation even worse is Android Studio's preview lack of precision.

like is there any way to create something like separate XML layouts for separate classes of display?

Comment: have you tried `marginRight` and `marginLeft` properties of the buttons?

Comment: @Gourav I know I can use margins but you see the button is taking much larger space in the Note 3 and if I add margin it would make it even worse

Comment: Use `ConstraintLayout` with `GuideLines` to achieve multiscreen support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [link from the official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes) will help you.

Things you can do to support different screen sizes are:

- Avoiding usage of absolute values
- If you use absolute values, use `dp` for sizes and `sp` for font sizes
- Use `match_parent` or `wrap_content` whenever possible
- If you use a `ConstraintLayout` `Guidelines` will probably be your friend (can create them % based)
- If nothing of the above helps, create a seperate layout for a different screensize ([explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44962692/android-layouts-for-different-screen-sizes))

Answer (score 1):

It's either use ConstraintLayout with GuideLines or use different layouts for different screen sizes.For example, you can create a layout named main_activity that's optimized for handsets and tablets by creating different versions of the file in directories as follows:

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For handsets (smaller than 600dp available width)
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
```

Here's how other smallest width values correspond to typical screen sizes:

```
320dp: a typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800 hdpi, etc).
480dp: a large phone screen ~5" (480x800 mdpi).
600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).
720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).
```

[image]

Check out the docs:
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support#DeclaringTabletLayouts